# setContentView...Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am currently refactoring the login page of my test app, and cant seem to figure out why I keep running into this error every time setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page) executes.

### error triggered at "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page)" in LoginPageActivity.java

```
com.example.jake.fieldinttest E: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                             Process: com.example.jake.fieldinttest, PID: 15597
                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jake.fieldinttest/com.example.jake.fieldinttest.LoginPage.LoginPageActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.jake.fieldinttest.LoginPage.LoginPageFragment did not create a view.
                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3545)
                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:330)
                                 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414)
                                 at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414)
                                 at com.example.jake.fieldinttest.LoginPage.LoginPageActivity.onCreate(LoginPageActivity.java:26)
                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I am refactoring the login page to follow an MVP architecture, which I have successfully implemented for the other pages of my application, however for the initial Login page I get the error.  It seems that maybe it could be that the view is not created/inflated before it can be set, but why would that pose a problem here and not in any other page of my application?  I have this page modeled just as the others down to the XML file. The only difference is that it is the first page of the application.  Maybe a Manifest problem being the launcher page?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

## LoginPageActivity.java

```
package com.example.jake.fieldinttest.LoginPage;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.example.jake.fieldinttest.R;
import com.example.jake.fieldinttest.TestingModuleRepository;
import com.example.jake.fieldinttest.Util.ActivityUtils;



public class LoginPageActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    private LoginPageFragment loginPageFragment;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);



        //set fragment to activity
        loginPageFragment = (LoginPageFragment) 
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.loginpage_fragment);
        if (loginPageFragment == null){
            loginPageFragment = new LoginPageFragment();

ActivityUtils.addFragmentToActivity(getSupportFragmentManager(), loginPageFragment, R.id.loginpage_fragment);
        }

        //create the presenter
        new LoginPresenter(
            TestingModuleRepository.getInstance(),
            loginPageFragment);
    }
}




package com.example.jake.fieldinttest.LoginPage;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.example.jake.fieldinttest.TestingModuleRepository;
```

## LoginPresenter.java

```
public class LoginPresenter implements LoginContract.Presenter {

private final TestingModuleRepository mModuleRepository;
private final LoginContract.View mLoginView;



public LoginPresenter(
        @NonNull TestingModuleRepository moduleRepository,
        @NonNull LoginContract.View loginView) {


    mModuleRepository = moduleRepository;
    mLoginView = loginView;

    mLoginView.setPresenter(this);
}


@Override
public void start(){}


public void buttonClicked() {}

}
```

## LoginPageFragment.java

```
package com.example.jake.fieldinttest.LoginPage;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


public class LoginPageFragment extends Fragment implements 
LoginContract.View {


private LoginContract.Presenter mPresenter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
  }

public LoginPageFragment(){

    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mPresenter.start();
}

@Override
public void setPresenter(@NonNull LoginContract.Presenter presenter) {
    mPresenter = presenter;
}



@Override
public void displayIncorrectLoginToast() {

}
}
```

## LoginContract.java

```
package com.example.jake.fieldinttest.LoginPage;


import com.example.jake.fieldinttest.BasePresenter;
import com.example.jake.fieldinttest.BaseView;


public interface LoginContract {
interface View extends BaseView<Presenter> {
    void displayIncorrectLoginToast();
}



interface Presenter extends BasePresenter {
    void buttonClicked();
}
}
```

## activity_main_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/page_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <fragment class = "com.example.jake.fieldinttest.LoginPage.LoginPageFragment"
        android:id="@+id/loginpage_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

## AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.jake.fieldinttest">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.setup.PLAY_SETUP_SERVICE"/>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".LoginPage.LoginPageActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <activity

        android:name=".FleetPage.FleetListPageActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.jake.fieldinttest.FleetPage.FleetListPageActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity

        android:name=".MainMenuPage.MainMenuActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.jake.fieldinttest.MainMenuPage.MainMenuActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity

        android:name=".PanelViewPage.PanelViewMain">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.jake.fieldinttest.PanelViewPage.PanelViewMain" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapPage.TotalMapViewPage">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.jake.fieldinttest.MapPage.TotalMapViewPage" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <activity

        android:name=".SomeNewPage">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.jake.fieldinttest.SomeNewPage" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You should implement `onCreateView` in your `LoginPageFragment`

Comment: I can add it, but i still get the same error regardless

Comment: If you call `super.onCreateView` you are not implementing it. You should inflate your layout there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two main ways to work with Fragments, you can check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), These ways are: fragment within a Activity's layout or via Java code. Seems that u're using the first one, fragment being declared in a Activity's layout XML.

In LogingPagerFragement.java you should override the onCreateView, and returning a View inflated by the layout's fragment. Your code would look like that:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment,
                          container, false);
   return v;  }
```

Although I strongly recommend implement the second way, this should work.

Comment: I found the problem. I was not differentiating between the parent class and the child class in the activity_main_page.xml file.  Rather than set the parent class to the content view then inflating the child fragment within, I was setting the child fragment itself and then trying to inflate another fragment within which was never declared. That's why I kept getting no view for fragment found.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: also android studio sometimes doesnt like the use of <fragment> so I changed it to <FrameLayout>